# positive integer solutions to $x^3+y^3=3^z$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I am seeking all positive integer solutions to the equation $x^3+y^3=3^z$.

After doing number crunching, I think there are no solutions. But I am unable to prove it.

**Attempt**

If $x$ and $y$ have common divisor $d$, we have $d^3(m^3+n^3)=3^z$. So $d$ must be a power of $3$, and we are back to where we started. So we assume $x$ and $y$ are coprime.

Testing the parity, we have sum of 2 cubes to be odd. WLOG, we can assume $x$ is even and $y$ is odd.

Trying mod $3$, we have $x+y=0 \pmod 3$. Since $x$ and $y$ are coprime, $x$ and $y$ must be congruent to $1$ and $-1$ or vice-versa.

If I assume $x=3m+1$ and $y=3n-1$, expand out and simplify, I get $27(m^3+n^3)+27(m^2-n^2)+9(m+n)=3^z$. If I assume $z \geq 3$, this gives $(m^3+n^3)+(m^2-n^2)+\frac{m+n}{3}=3^{z-3}$. But I don't see how to proceed.

I also tried mod $9$ but didn't get anywhere, it didn't cut down the possibilities by much.

I also tried letting $y=x+r$. Then
\begin{align*}
x^3+y^3 &= x^3+(x+r)^3 \\
&= x^3 + (x^3+3x^2r+3xr^2+r^3) \\
&= 2x^3+3x^2r+3xr^2+r^3 \\
&= 3^z
\end{align*}

Then $3\mid 2x^3+3x^2r+3xr^2+r^3$, and $3\mid 3x^2r+3xr^2$, so this implies $3 \mid 2x^3+r^3$. But this doesn't yield any contradiction.

Can anyone supply a proof? Or if my hypothesis is wrong, how to derive all the integer solutions?

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe concentrate on $z$?  It can’t be a multiple of $3$, due to Fermat.

Comment: Are you familiar with the Lifting Exponent Lemma? Thus is a classic example of this. I think that there are an article in www.mathlinks.ro

Comment: @RicardoLargaespada Can we apply it here? the LTE requires $p \mid x-y$

Comment: Also you have to read Zsigmondy Theorem, the solution by this technique is awesome

Comment: I'm confused; isn't $(x,y,z)=(1,2,2)$ a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$27(m^3+n^3) +27(m^2-n^2) + 9(m+n) = 3^z$

$(m+n)(3m^2 +3n^2-3mn+3m-3n+1) = 3^{z-2}$

since $z \ne 2$, we have $3(m^2 +n^2-mn+m-n)+1$ divides a power of $3$ or is equal to $1$, both of which is not possible.

Comment: Now that you write it out, it seems really obvious XD. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome :)

Comment: But it *is* equal to $1$ for $(m,n)=(0,1)$. And why *"...since $z\neq2$..."*? It would make more sense to infer that
$$3(m^2 +n^2-mn+m-n)+1,$$
must be a power of $3$, which happens only if it equals $1$, and from here *conclude* that $z=2$.

Answer (score 3):

You already proved that we can assume that $x,y$ are relatively prime.

We can find easly solution for $n\leq 2$. Let $n\geq 3$.

So $x+y = 3^a$ and $x^2-xy+y^2=3^b$ for some nonegative integers $a+b=n$.

If $b\geq 2$ then $9\mid x^2-xy+y^2$ and $3\mid x+y$, so $$9\mid (x+y)^2-(x^2-xy+y^2)=3xy\implies 3\mid xy$$
A contradiction. So $b\leq 2$ and this should be easly done.

Comment: that is really an ingenious way to show it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Solution by LTE, let $d=(x,y)>1$, $x=dx_1$, $y=dy_1$, $(x_1,y_q)=1$ then $$d^3\mid x^3+y^3=3^z$$ then $d\mid 3^a$ for a positive integer $a<z/3$. Dividing by $d^3$ we obtain $x^3_1+y^3_1=3^b$, for a positive integer $b=z-a$. This is a equation similar to the original, then we can assume $(x,y)=1$. If $3\nmid x+y$ then $x+y=1$ a contradiction. Then we have all the conditions to use LTE: $$v_3(x^3+y^3)=v_3(x+y)+v_3(3)=v_3(x+y)
+1=v_3(3^z)=z$$ From here we conclude that $x+y=3^{z-1}$ this implies that $x^2-xy+y^2=3$, $(x-y)^2+xy=3$, if $|x-y|\ge 2$ we have a contradiction, then there are two cases:
Case 1. $|x-y|=0$  this is not possible due $x$ and $y$ are coprimes and $x+y>2$.
Case 2. $|x-y|=1$ implying $xy=2$, with solutions $(x,y)=(2,1)$ or $(1,2)$, implying $3^{z-1}=2+1\Rightarrow z=2$.

Then the solutions to the original equation are: $(x,y,z)=(3^k,2\cdot 3^k,3k+2)$ or $(2\cdot 3^k, 3^k,3k+2)\forall k\in \mathbb{N}$.